# CSS not working in Laravel project deployed to Google Cloud Run

Tags: css, laravel, docker, google-cloud-run

I deployed a dockerized Laravel project to Google Cloud Run. The CSS works great locally. When I go to the page that is hosted, there are no styles applied. When I inspect the page, I see that the CSS has been found and is correct, but the styles are not applied.

[image: Proof that it is seeing my CSS]

Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine


RUN apk add --no-cache nginx wget

RUN mkdir -p /run/nginx

COPY docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

RUN mkdir -p /app
COPY . /app

RUN sh -c "wget http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar && chmod a+x composer.phar && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer"
RUN cd /app && \
    /usr/local/bin/composer install --no-dev

RUN chown -R www-data: /app

CMD sh /app/docker/startup.sh
```

Comment: Use the Chrome debugger and do a "hard reload". If you are changing the CSS and not changing the CSS filename, caching can be your enemy.

Comment: @JohnHanley, great suggestion, I was really hoping that would fix it but it did not. I even tried on a different device JUST to make sure it wasn't caching.

Comment: Can you include in question if there's an error in Cloud Logging or Cloud Run > Service > Logs?

Comment: I converted my scss to css and it works fine. I guess I have to figure out why sass isn't working, but at least now my page looks normal.